# vue js 2 sorting a table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have 2 questions with vue.js 2 and a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tmun9cxa/1/

1. When you click a column header, why does my sorting not work? What is the solution?
2. How do I go about making the search input field search only the pn column?

A lot of the examples ive found are using vue1 and out of date.

```
<input type="text" value="" v-model="search" placeholder="Search">

<table style="text-align: center;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th v-for="column in columns">
                <a 
                    href="#"
                    v-on:click="sort(column.shortcode)">{{column.label}}
                </a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(product) in products">
            <td>{{product.pn}}</td>
            <td>{{product.od}}</td>
            <td>{{product.id}}</td>
            <td>{{product.thickness}}</td>
            <td>{{product.lo}}</td>
            <td>{{product.weight}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

javascript here

```
var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            currentSort: 'pn',
            currentSortDir: 'asc',
            search: '',
            columns: [
                { label: 'P/N', shortcode: 'pn' },
                { label: 'OD (De,mm)', shortcode: 'od' },
                { label: 'ID (De,mm)', shortcode: 'id' },
                { label: 'Thickness (De,mm)', shortcode: 'thickness' },
                { label: 'LO', shortcode: 'lo' },
                { label: 'Weight (kg/1000)', shortcode: 'weight' },
            ], // columns
            products: [
                { 
                    pn: 170158,
                    od: 13,
                    id: .44,
                    thickness: 1,
                    lo: .45,
                    weight: .7
                },{ 
                    pn: 1803561,
                    od: 12,
                    id: .8,
                    thickness: .7,
                    lo: .11,
                    weight: .5
                },{ 
                    pn: 170149,
                    od: 9,
                    id: .64,
                    thickness: .6,
                    lo: .75,
                    weight: .3
                },{ 
                    pn: 150149,
                    od: 15,
                    id: .22,
                    thickness: .3,
                    lo: .55,
                    weight: .9
                },
            ], // products
        },
        methods: {
            sort:function(col) {
                //console.log( 'current: '+this.currentSort );
                //console.log( 'col: '+col );
                //var colthing = col;

                // if you click the same label twice
                if(this.currentSort == col){
                    console.log( 'same col: '+col );
                    // sort by asc
                    this.products = this.products.sort((a, b) => {
                        return a.col >= b.col;
                    });
                }else{
                    this.currentSort = col;
                    console.log( 'diff col: '+col );
                    // sort by desc
                    this.products = this.products.sort((a, b) => {
                        return a.col <= b.col;
                    });
                } // end if

            }, // sort

        }, // methods
    }); // vue
```

Comment: uses `a[col]` instead of `a.col`, `b[col]` instead of `b.col`. you can `console.log(a.col, b.col)` before `return a.col >=b.col` then you will see what is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the column sorting , as pointed out, was not working because you need to use `a[col]` instead of `a.col`

Also, you should consider using a computed value instead of modifying the original data. This makes filtering easier too.

here is the updated script (note that `<tr v-for="(product) in products">` needs to be `<tr v-for="(product) in showProducts">` for this to work)

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentSort: 'pn',
    currentSortDir: 'asc',
    search: '',
    columns: [
      { label: 'P/N', shortcode: 'pn' },
      /// more columns ...
    ], // columns
    products: [
      //.... objects
    ], // products
  },
  computed: {
    showProducts() {
      return this.products.filter(a => {
        console.log(a.pn)
        return (a.pn + '').includes(this.search)
      })
        .sort((a, b) => {
        if (this.currentSortDir === 'asc') {
         return a[this.currentSort] >= b[this.currentSort];      
        }
        return a[this.currentSort] <= b[this.currentSort];
      })
    },
  },
  methods: {
    sort:function(col) {
      // if you click the same label twice
      if(this.currentSort == col){
        this.currentSortDir = this.currentSortDir === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
      }else{
        this.currentSort = col;
        console.log( 'diff col: '+col );
      } // end if

    }, // sort

  }, // methods
}); // vue
```

finally, the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tmun9cxa/2/

Comment: Thanks this works great. What if I want to add multiple filters? I just added a select input and added property to the products here: https://jsfiddle.net/tmun9cxa/3/

Comment: you had the right idea, but you need to use `''` instead of `'all'`. the `includes` function using `all` will not find anything